# Jib is always executed on a Gradle multi-project

Tags: gradle, jib

We have a multi-project structure with Gradle as a build tool. The problem is that the jib extension is executed even when we do a:

```
./gradlew :A:jar
```

So we try to surround it with a custom task:

```
task doJib {
   doLast {
      jib {
         from
            ...
   }
```

Now when we execute:

```
./gradlew :A:doJib jibDockerBuild {parameter}
```

Then jibDockerBuild is also executed for project B. But the parameter is only valid for project A. This leads to errors.

Is it possible to execute jib only for project A?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are using Jib in version 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution was:

```
./gradlew :A:doJib :A:jibDockerBuild {parameter}
```